# need of eigenvalue for a nontrivial solution

Tags: linear-algebra

A scalar $\lambda$ is called an eigenvalue of a matrix $A$  if there is a nontrivial solution $\vec x$ of $A\vec x = \lambda \vec x$, such that $\vec x$ is called an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$.

What I don't understand is why should there be a nontrivial solution at all. If the solution is unique, the value of lambda would still exist, right? Suppose for a matrix $A$ the value of $\lambda$ say 3, has a trivial solution for the equation: $A \vec x - 3 \vec x= \vec 0$(Which is essentially the same as above), then there would be just one single vector that would satisfy the above equation. Why can't we say that this unique vector is an eigenvector? And $\lambda = 3$ is an eigenvalue?

Comment: A non-trivial solution essentially means $x\neq\mathbf0$

Comment: @BillWallis, I mean in the case of trivial solution.

Comment: @BillWallis, yeah, that was correct and I got a demo in the answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Note that 
$$
\boldsymbol A \boldsymbol 0 = \lambda \boldsymbol 0
$$
for all $\lambda$, hence if the solution is unique, then it must be $\boldsymbol 0$ which is not of much interest.

Comment: I think I've figured why scientists go mad, I'm not a scientist but, when one studies maths for straight 8 hrs, he begins to forget what he read an hour ago. But this is the perfect answer.

Comment: @mathmaniage Thanks. Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

You can also think of it this way: matrices correspond to some kind of transformation.

If you consider $2$-dimensional vectors, then matrices will transform, say, a square by enlarging it, or rotating it, or shearing it, and so on. The *eigenvectors* are the set of vectors who are *only* changed by a scalar multiple when you apply the transformation to them. That is, they're the vectors whose direction stays the same, and only their length differs.

Now, *why are there always non-trivial eigenvectors*? It's a slightly tricky question, which I can only answer part of: the eigenvalues $\lambda$ are found by solving
$$
\det(A-\lambda I_{n}) = 0
$$
for $\lambda$. Such a $\lambda$ must *always* exist (it's not always real, it can be complex) since $\det(A-\lambda I_{n})$ is a polynomial and every polynomial has a root (this is the [Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra)). Note that if the eigenvalue is not real, then the eigenvector also will not be real. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654465/do-all-square-matrices-have-eigenvectors/654470) for more.

Comment: another question came to mind, that I didn't want to make a post of, are the basis of eigenspace themselves eigenvectors? By analogy I'd say yes, but, don't think there is a proof or something?

Comment: Absolutely, in fact one constructs the eigenspace by taking the linear combination of the eigenvectors, so that your question is true by definition once one shows that the eigenvectors are linearly independent (I'm not sure where to find such a proof though).

Comment: ....and, is linear independence affected by transposition? and how do I prove this? (I didn't really come across these proofs through the book)

Comment: What do you mean by transposition? It's not a term that I'm familiar with.

Comment: transpose of  the matrix A

Comment: For a _square matrix_ $A$, then no. This follows from the fact that the row rank equals the column rank in _any_ matrix (see [the Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra))), so that if you have a square matrix with linearly independent rows (or columns), then it must have linearly independent columns (or rows).